# What is the error in this sql

Tags: php, sql, oracle

What is wrong with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM leaderboard WHERE ALREADYWON != '1' ORDER BY Score LIMIT 0,'$limit'
```

Code after it just throws errors:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in file ...
```

`$limit` definitely has a value, I'm echoing it out just before. I'm using Oracle.

Can anyone spot a syntax error?

Comment: If you can paste your errors too, it may help finding the cause.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\coke\setup.php on line 17 - doesn't really help does it.

Comment: Which SQL are you using?

Comment: ORACLE does not support `LIMIT` AFAIK. You would use `row_number()`

Comment: Ah that's it...ORACLE doesn't support LIMIT!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORACLE doesn't support LIMIT. I had to use this query

```
SELECT * FROM leaderboard 
WHERE rownum <= '$limit' 
AND ALREADYWON != '1' 
ORDER BY Score
```

Comment: Spot on about LIMIT not being valid syntax in Oracle.  But you can't have the ROWNUM limit condition at the same level of nesting as the ORDER BY because the ROWNUM is assigned before the rows are ordered.  Your query would return an arbitrary `$limit` rows and then order the result.  You'd need something like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM leaderboard WHERE AlreadyWon != '1' ORDER BY SCORE) WHERE rownum <= <<limit>>`

Comment: Ah, that's why I'm not getting exactly the results I need. Thanks for taking the time! Should that query be SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM leaderboard WHERE AlreadyWon != '1' ORDER BY SCORE) leaderboard WHERE rownum <= <<limit>>

Answer (score 5):

Oracle does not support the LIMIT keyword.  The equivalent construct in Oracle would be something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM leaderboard
         WHERE AlreadyWon != '1'
         ORDER BY score)
 WHERE rownum <= <<limit>>
```

Note that this is **NOT** equivalent to the query

```
SELECT *
  FROM leaderboard
 WHERE AlreadyWon != '1'
   AND rownum <= <<limit>>
 ORDER BY score
```

The first query gets the first `<<limit>>` rows based on the `SCORE` order.  The second query gets an arbitrary set of `<<limit>>` rows and orders that arbitrary set because the ROWNUM filter is applied before the ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

Is ALREADYWON really a string? Shouldn't the comparison be using <> instead of != ?

Comment: this query runs fine....it's something to do with the limit at the end: SELECT * FROM leaderboard WHERE ALREADYWON != 1 ORDER BY SCORE

Comment: @elduderino - The query may run.  But it does seem odd to have a VARCHAR2 column that stores a numeric value.  If AlreadyWon is actually a numeric column, forcing implicit data type conversion may impact performance.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing PHP into a SQL statement is the problem. Everything after this...

```
SELECT * FROM leaderboard WHERE ALREADYWON != '1' ORDER BY Score
```

... will likely be the cause of your error

Also, its considered poor practice to 'SELECT *' for any table. You should be naming the columns explicitly.

After looking at some of your responses, it looks like you are trying to get TOP N records. For oracle, [this](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_select_the_top_n_rows_from_a_table) is a few of the ways to get them (kind of dated, but should still work).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the != is wrong and should be <> to be a valid query. Also I don't know but '$limit' should perhaps be '".$limit."'. GL!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT score, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY score) R FROM leaderboard WHERE alreadywon != 1)
   WHERE R BETWEEN 0 and '$Limit';
```

This will get you scores ordered but up to the limit you specified.  Be careful though, as this is a candidate for SQL Injection.  You might want to look into PHP parameterized queries instead.